# Distribution of highest numbered occupied box and number of balls therein?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Say we have $N$ boxes, numbered $1,2,...,N$.

We select $K$ numbers uniformly from $1,2,...,N$, and for each result we place one ball into the correspondingly numbered box.

We then select $L$ numbers uniformly from the same $1,2,...,N$ and for each result we remove one ball (if any are left) from the corresponding box.

In both iterations, the numbers are selected with replacement.
The boxes have no capacity limit, that is, more than one ball can be placed into any given box.

To clarify the mechanic, say we had 4 boxes, and we'd tossed some number $K$ balls into them as specified. Now, say $L$ was 4, and the resulting samples of numbers were ${1,3,4,4}$. We'd remove one ball from box 1 (if any were there), one ball from box 3 (if any...), and two balls from box 4 (if any were there, so if box 4 had 2 or fewer balls it will be left empty).

I'm interested in the probability distribution of the highest numbered occupied box (if any) and the associated number of remaining balls in that box.

I've written a couple of methods in my CAS to arrive at the result, one simply enumerating the multinomial possibilities and doing the corresponding machinations, the other using a generating function and pulling the coefficients with corresponding machinations.

As requested in comments, an example for the results for the case of $N=6$ boxes, $K=3$ tosses, and $L=2$ removals is as follows (left column is box number, followed left-to-right with probabilities that box is the highest numbered occupied box, with number of remaining balls $1,2,3$ seen there):

[image]

Both work fine up to $K$ and $L$ of 15 with $N$ up to ~6, but the complexity of the methods means it gets slow pretty quickly.

Is there a more efficient means to arrive at the desired results?

Comment: When you select the numbers, is that with or without replacement?  Can you put more than one ball in a box?

Comment: @RossMillikan - With replacement, boxes have no capacity limit. I'll add that clarification to the question.

Comment: "the probability distribution of the highest numbered occupied box (if any) and the associated number of remaining balls in that box." Sounds rather redundant, no? The probability distribution is of, precisely, the number of balls in the box with maximum number of balls (after the removal), no?

Comment: Also, you might add some numerical results to check

Comment: @leonbloy - "The probability distribution is of, precisely, the number of balls in the box with maximum number of balls (after the removal), no? "

No. It is the quantity in the *highest numbered box*, e.g., if there are 4 boxes, box 4 ends up empty, box 3 has one ball, box 2 has ten balls, box 3 is the largest numbered occupied box. 

I shall add a numeric result example as requested.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had misunderstood it

Comment: Do you always remove exactly $L$ balls? Or if you pick an empty box during one of the removal steps, do you not remove any balls and move on? Because if you always remove exactly $L$ balls, that's just the same as placing $K - L$ balls into $N$ boxes.

Comment: @RiversMcForge - Say we had 4 boxes. Say $L$ was 4, and the resulting samples were ${1,3,4,4}$. We'd remove one ball from box 1 (if any were there), one ball from box 3 (if any...), and two balls from box 4 (if any were there, so if box 4 had 2 or fewer balls it will be left empty).

Comment: OK, so from your response I gather that you might end up removing less than $L$ balls, if you picked some empty boxes. That makes the problem more interesting.

Comment: I don’t know if this is easier to think about, but maybe it’s the same problem? (Basically, let boxes have a negative number of balls.)

There are $N$ people standing on the $x$-axis, at the points $(i,0)$. Now, $K$ times in a row, a random one if them is told to move one unit in the positive $y$-direction. Then $L$ times in a row, one of them is told to move one unit in the negative $y$-direction. Let $Y$ be the vertical position of the rightmost person strictly above the $x$-axis. What is the distribution of $Y$? (Presumably $L<K$ so there is necessarily a nonempty box?)

Comment: The number of balls in any one given bin is going to be $Y = \max(0, X)$ where $X = A - B$ where $A \perp B$, $A$ is binomial with parameters $K, 1/N$ and $B$ is also binomial with parameters $L, 1/N$. Is the distribution asked simply $P(Y = k |. Y > 0)$? As Steve above notes, things should reasonably break if $L > K$, though I am not sure either way. (The word "highest numbered" is pretty redundant since the numbers are kind of arbitrary I think, but "unoccupied" is not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your unrefined probability with $n$ being the largest occupied box, you effectively want to count the number of sequences of pairs
$$((A_1, B_1), \ldots, (A_N, B_N))$$
where

1. $(A_1, \ldots, A_N)$ is an ordered set partition of $\{1, \ldots, K\}$,
2. $(B_1, \ldots, B_N)$ is an ordered set partition of $\{1, \ldots, L\}$,
3. $|A_n| > |B_n|$, and
4. $|A_i| \leq |B_i|$ for $i > n$.

(These ordered set partitions allow empty blocks.)

Using standard theory of bivariate exponential generating functions, this count is
$$\left[\frac{x^K}{K!} \frac{y^L}{L!}\right] e^{(n-1)(x+y)} G_>(x, y) G_{\leq}(x, y)^{N-n} \qquad (*)$$
where
$$G_>(x, y) = \sum_{i>j\geq 0} \frac{x^i}{i!} \frac{y^j}{j!}$$
and
$$G_{\leq}(x, y) = \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} \frac{x^i}{i!} \frac{y^j}{j!}.$$
Divide (*) by $N^{K+L}$ to get the probability.

While $G_>$ and $G_{\leq}$ don't meaningfully simplify, we can truncate them with $i \leq K$ and $j \leq L$, toss them into a CAS to do the polynomial multiplications quickly, and then extract coefficients. If you want to do this for fixed $N, n$ and many $K, L$, I doubt you'll get anything faster. Of course, if you want asymptotics in certain regimes, torturing (*) would be a good place to start. For fixed $N, n$ you should be able to use singularity analysis to determine behavior for large $K, L$.

"Nicer" answers would likely imply simplifications to (*), which probably don't exist, so I wouldn't be hopeful for such things.

You can get the more refined probability with $n$ being the largest occupied box and $m$ being the number of balls in it by replacing (3) with $|A_n| = |B_n|+m$ and replacing (*) with
$$\left[\frac{x^K}{K!} \frac{y^L}{L!}\right] e^{(n-1)(x+y)} G_m(x, y) G_{\leq}(x, y)^{N-n} \qquad (**)$$

where
$$G_m(x, y) = \sum_{j \geq 0} \frac{x^{j+m}}{(j+m)!} \frac{y^j}{j!}.$$

I implemented this (not well) in Mathematica. It certainly slows down quickly, but I for instance did the $K=20, L=16, N=30, n=10, m=6$ case in about 10 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's fantastic - I completely missed the counting correspondence you show. This fits my needs perfectly. +1 and accept.